# Find the equation of a plane which is parallel to a line

Tags: vectors

> A line $l$ has equation $r = ( -7i - 3j) + \lambda( 2i - 2j + 3k)$ , for $\lambda$ is a real number.
>
> A plane $X$ passes through the points $( 1 , 3 ,5 )$ and $( 5 , 2 ,5 )$ , and is parallel to $l$.
>
> (i) Find an equation of $X$ , giving the answer in the form $r.n = p$.
>
> (ii) Find the distance between $l$ and $X$.
>
> (iii) Find an equation of the line which is the reflection of $l$ in $X$ , giving the answer in the form $r = a + tb$.

In my opinion , I will get the result of product between a direction vector of a line on the plane and the direction vector of  the line $l$ .Then, I can get the normal vector of plane $X$. I am not sure that is a right solution, is that right? If not, please give me the right solution for these questions.

Comment: Yes, that is right. What are those two direction vectors?

Comment: 1,:( 2,- ,3 ,3)
2.: (4 , -1 , 0 )

Comment: Typo, should be (2, -2, 3). Cross product to give n then use either point on the plane to find its equation.

Comment: First of all , thank you so much . Secondly , Absolute of normal vector , in this case , is the distance between the plane and line l, isn't it ?

Comment: Unlikely. The absolute value of p will be the distance of the plane from the origin if you normalize n. If you can find the perpendicular distance of the line from the origin you can subtract the two.